# How to restrict users access to database in firebase firestore?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, user-defined-functions

My requirement:

Total No of users:4

User1:Can submit his data. And if he pressed a button he can able see all 4users data.
Same like for other 3users also.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: please share screenshot of your database

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to structure your database something like this:

```
users: {
  userId1: {
    ...userData
  }
}
```

Basically you need to separate data of each user in separate nodes.

Then use these security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
        ".read": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now the user can write to his/her data only but everyone can read it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use database security rules, https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

and i suggest you structure your data in database like
`/data/<userId>` and limit the user write access to its `userId`

of course you also need to implement firebase auth.